# Ganache Fork Fantom Mainnet Gas Token

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, ganache, fantom

I have forked fantom network with using Ganache but now the problem is that I dont have any FTM on my Forked-Fantom chain since Ganache auto create accounts with 100 Eth only. Any advice for me ?

How can I swap some FTM with eth on my forked-Fantom local network ?

How can I get FTM token for accounts that ganache auto creates on my Forked Fantom Blockchain ?

Going crazy

Answer (score -2):

The 100 Eth from Ganache is 100 FTM in your fork.